# Prove that the curves $y^2=4ax$ and $xy=c^2$ cut at right angles, if $c^4=32a^4$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove that the curves $y^2=4ax$ and $xy=c^2$ cut at right angles, if $c^4=32a^4$

I tried finding the slope of both the curves, i.e., $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ of both the curves, and since they are perpendicular, the product of the slopes is $-1$. However, I could not really solve it. Please help.

Comment: You need to find the slopes _at the point of intersection_, and show that _those_ slopes are perpendicular (the slopes aren't perpendicular everywhere, that doesn't even make sense). So the first thing you need to do is to find the point of intersection.

Comment: @Arthur Okay, on it. Do they come out to be $\bigg(\dfrac{c^2}{(4ac^2)^{1/3}},(4ac^2)^{1/3}\bigg)$

Comment: I don't have pen and paper with me, so I can't confirm with absolute certainty, but it seems reasonable (that point looks to me like it belongs to both curves, but there are too many fractions and $^{1/3}$ for me to be certain). Now, what are the slopes of the two curves at that point?

Comment: @Arthur Got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Arthur I got the euqation $-\dfrac{4ac^2}{2yx^2}=-1$ and substituted the above values and got the solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do that is to compute the gradients at a point $(x,y)$ of the functions which define the two curves $f\left(x,y\right)=y^{2}-4ax$ and $g\left(x,y\right)=xy-c^{2}$.
The respective gradients are $\left(\begin{array}{c}
-4a\\
2y
\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{c}
y\\
x
\end{array}\right)$, so their scalar product is $y\left(2x-4a\right)$. If the two curves
intersect at $\left(x,y\right)$, you can compute the coordinates $x$ and $y$ and then deduce the scalar product as a function of $a$ and $c$, and check that the latter vanishes when $c^{4}=32a^{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let point of intersection be $(x_o, y_o)$. The slope of parabola is $y' = \frac{2a}{y_o}$ and of hyperbola is $\frac{-c^2}{x_o^2}$. 
Product of slope is $-1$ for perpendicular intersection:

$$\frac{2a}{y_o}=\frac{x_o^2}{c^2}\\
x^2_o y_o = 2ac^2 $$
The point $(x_o, y_o)$ satisfies both the parabola and hyperbola. So it satisfies their equation:
$$\\ \implies x_o = 2a$$

Now we get $y_o = \frac{c^2}{2a}$. Put in parabola equation

$$\frac{x^4}{4a^2} = 4a \cdot 2a$$

which is the required answer :)

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2=4ax$$ $$xy=c^2$$

As Arthur pointed, we need to find their point of intersection and calculate $dy\over{dx}$ of both curves at this point.

(Note that this is angle of tangents at that point, we cannot calculate the true angle due to mathematical limitations.)

Put $x$ from first equation into the other.

We get, $$\frac{y^3}{4a}=c^2 $$ Now use the given relation, $c^4=32a^4$

you get, $$\frac{y^6}{16a^2}=32a^4$$
$$y^6=512a^6$$
$$y=2^{3/2}a$$

Using this we get, $x=2a$

Calculating derivatives, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4a}{x}}$

Placing 2a $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Other equation, $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{c^2}{x^2}$

Placing x=2a, $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt{2}$

Their product is -1, **Hence proved.**

Answer (score 0):

WLOG any point on $y^2=4ax$ is $(at^2,2at)$

At the point$(P)$ of intersection $$c^2=at^2\cdot2at\iff t^3=\dfrac{c^2}{2a^2}\ \ 
 \ \  \ (1)$$

Now the gradient of $y^2=4ax$ at $P$ is $$\dfrac{4a}{2(2at)}=\dfrac1t$$

and that of $xy=c^2$ $$-\dfrac{2at}{at^2}=-\dfrac2t$$

We need $-\dfrac2t\cdot\dfrac1t=-1\implies t^2=2$

Replace this value of $t$ in $(1)$